# angular-cli : Import node_modules files in src directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli architecture for the initial setup of the app.

I want to import some of global css files into my index.html file. But as node_modules directory is outside of my src directory i'm not getting the accurate path and hence css is not applying.

I'm using path in following meaner,

I have tried without ../ also but it's also not working.

for ex.

```
<link href="node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**&&**

```
<link href="../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

But both the ways are not working.

Is anything wrong i'm doing?

Here is the app structure.

[image]

I'm using angular 2.2.1

Here is the error i'm getting

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) Are you getting a 404 error? Are you serving `node_modules` over your server?

Comment: Yes. I have updated question with screen

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844334/add-the-css-from-the-node-modules-folder-using-angular-cli) will help you

Comment: I'm not having the angular-cli-build.js file. You can see in screenshort.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) of angular CLI on how to install global libraraies,

you have to modify your `angular-cli.json` file to include css files in bundled style file not use directly in the HTML.

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css"
]
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Madhu
Added the path in angular-cli.json but what should i write in index.html?

Comment: @PinankLakhani Nothing.

Comment: when you add it in styles folder, CLI bundles the file into `styles.bundle` so you don't have to add anything in your HTML, Cheers!!

Comment: still Not working. Its not applying the css

"styles": [
        "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.js"
      ],

Comment: you have to add css file not the JS file.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks madhu.

Comment: is it work for production too? I mean for dist folder?

Comment: It should, i don't see any reason why it won't, it is taking the css files and bundling it and it does it while you are creating a prod build.

Comment: I have tried one. On ng build it's making dist folder but i couldn't find the node_modules files. Still it will work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129869/discussion-between-pinank-lakhani-and-madhu-ranjan).

Comment: Hi Madhu, Its loading the files from node_modules but not loading the external css files which exist in my css directory.

Comment: Have you added external files into styles in CLI JSON?